# I have a problem with porting VBA code to Lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, ole

```
Sub ListaDokumentow()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim oSubGT As InsERT.Subiekt
    Dim oListaDok As InsERT.SuDokumentyLista
    Dim oDok As InsERT.SuDokument
    Dim sNapis As String
        
    Set oSubGT = UruchomSubiekta()
     
 
    Set oListaDok = oSubGT.Dokumenty.Wybierz()
    oListaDok.FiltrTypOpcje = gtaFiltrSuDokumentOpcjeZam
    oListaDok.FiltrTyp = gtaFiltrSuDokumentZam
    oListaDok.FiltrOkres = gtaFiltrOkresNieokreslony
    oListaDok.MultiSelekcja = True
    
    oListaDok.Wyswietl
    
    sNapis = "Zaznaczono nastęujące dokumenty: " & vbCrLf
    
    For Each oDok In oListaDok.ZaznaczoneDokumenty
        sNapis = sNapis & oDok.NumerPelny & "ID:" & oDok.Identyfikator & vbCrLf
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox sNapis
    
    
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Wystąpił błąd: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    
End Sub
```

I wrote such a code in VBA but I can not transfer it to Lazarus, it is about returning the invoice id and the invoice number

```
unit sm_testy;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, wps_u, LCLType,Comobj,variants,ActiveX;

type
  TOleCollectionEnumClass = class(TObject);
  TEkSmTesty = class(TForm)
  private

  public

  end;

var
  EkSmTesty: TEkSmTesty;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}


var
aSubGT,oSubGT:OleVariant;
oListGT,gtaFiltrOkresNieokreslony,gtaFiltrSuDokumentOpcjeZam,gtaFiltrSuDokumentZam:OleVariant;
oDok: OleVariant;
Reply, BoxStyle: Integer;

begin

BoxStyle := MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_YESNO;
//Reply := Application.MessageBox(PChar(IntToStr(PROG_VER_NUM_RC)),'Test', BoxStyle);

wpsConnect(oSubGT,true);

oListGT:=oSubGT.Dokumenty.Wybierz;
oListGT.FiltrTypOpcje:=15;
//oListGT.FiltrTyp:=gtaFiltrSuDokumentZam;
oListGT.FiltrOkres:=gtaFiltrOkresNieokreslony;
oListGT.MultiSelekcja:= True;
oListGT.Wyswietl;

end. // eof
```

I stopped at the display of window of "subiekt" with the list, and I do not know how to enumerate the oleVariant object

Maybe someone would at least lead me on the right path

I can't enumerate the oDok object in Lazarus, which in my opinion should look something like this

oDok: = CreateOleObject ('InsERT.SuDokument');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code in a separate utility unit:

```
Type
  TEatenType = {$ifdef fpc} {$ifdef ver3_0}pulong{$else}Ulong{$endif}{$else}Integer{$endif}; // type for eaten parameter MkParseDisplayName
  oEnumIterator = record
                      mainobj: OleVariant;
                      oEnum  : IEnumVariant;
                      IterItem : OleVariant;
                      IterVal  : LongWord;
                      function Enumerate(v:olevariant):oEnumIterator;
                      function GetEnumerator :oEnumIterator;
                      function MoveNext:Boolean;
                      property Current:OleVariant read iteritem;
                   end;


Implementation

{ oEnumIterator}

function oEnumIterator.getenumerator :oEnumIterator;
begin
 result:=self;
end;

Function oEnumIterator.Enumerate(v :olevariant):oEnumIterator;
begin
  mainobj:=v;
  oEnum  := IUnknown(mainobj._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  result:=self;
end;

Function  oEnumIterator.MoveNext:boolean;
begin
  result:=(oEnum.Next(1, iteritem, iterval) = s_ok);
end;
```

and then enumerate using

```
var  oEnum            : oEnumIterator;
     colItem,
     colItems : Olevariant
 ..
 colitems:=objWMIService.ExecQuery('Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem');
 for colItem in oEnum.Enumerate(colItems) do  
         memo1.lines.add('Version: ',colitem.Version);
```

Comment: Ok this is working good

Comment: It is then the social convention to accept/upvote it. :-)